# Extend Button class to create a singleton

Tags: java, android, button, singleton

I want to extend the `Button` class to create a *singleton* class called "`LabeledButton`" that will have also a `String` attribute called `label`.

That's so far where I got:

```
static public class LabeledButton extends Button {
    String label;

    private LabeledButton(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    static public LabeledButton getInstance(String label) {
        if(current == null)
            current = new LabeledButton(label);
        return current;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

But that's the error I get in my constructor:

> There is no default constructor available in 'android.widget.Button'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

**Default Constructor** is the constructor without any arguments, and is *implicitly introduced by Java compiler in case no other constructor is mentioned* .

Whenever You extend any given class, while creating object the parent class constructor is invoked first. In situations where Parent class doesn't offer a no args constructor You will have to explicitly tell which parameterized one to invoke.

As mentioned in the error

```
There is no default constructor available in 'android.widget.Button'
```

In current context Since you are extending Button, which happens not to have default (No args) constructor.

```
Button(Context context)
Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
```

are the only exposed ones. 
[Android Button Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html#Button(android.content.Context))

So you will have to explicity invoke one of the parameterized constructor.

```
public class LabeledButton extends Button {
    String label;

    public LabeledButton(Context context, String label) {
        super(context);  // Explicitly Invoking the parent parameterized constructor 
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like the error says you need to add the default constructor for the [Button class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html), try changing your constructor to the following.

```
public class LabeledButton extends Button {
    String label;

    public LabeledButton(Context context, String label) {
        super(context);
        this.label = label;
    }

    static public LabeledButton getInstance(Context context, String label) {
        if(current == null)
            current = new LabeledButton(context, label);
        return current;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how about `getInstance()`? Which context should I add in the arguments?

Comment: Updated to include getInstance()